# hogan is transforming & to &amp

Tags: mustache, hogan.js

I use hogan to render a xml Templates and I have a list of URLs including &.
Before render templates everything is ok, after render all & are tranformed to &amp. How can I abviate this action?

I do not want to replace it before saveing, because the function is compile, render and save the template and is used by other functions. Mabye I need to write &amp later.

Answer (score 0):

ok I think i found the problem by my own. It is not about hogan it is about xml. Xml do not allow & so it completly correct to transform &.